# Apache HTTP Client and conditional setting of proxy

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am instantiating an Apache HTTP Components HttpClient using the following code:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyServerAddress, proxyServerPort))
        .disableConnectionState()
        .disableCookieManagement()
        .build();
```

But I would like to set the proxy only if an property (e.g. `useProxy`) is set to `true`. I can use an `if-then-else` pair of blocks based on the property value, but I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve this? My goal is to externalize the control of whether or not to use a proxy, using a configuration file property or via `JAVA_OPTS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClients.custom()
        .disableConnectionState()
        .disableCookieManagement();

if( useProxy )
    builder = builder.setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyServerAddress, proxyServerPort));

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = builder.build();
```